# glibc-2.15 cannot remove `/var/db/Makefile'

Tags: gcc, centos, glibc

When trying to install glibc-2.15 on Centos-5(Kernel version `2.6.18-238.9.1.el5, gcc-4.6.3`), ***make install*** step fails with the error message  `cannot remove`/var/db/Makefile'`

The configure command is `/data1/downloads/gcc/utils/glibc-2.15/configure --prefix=/data1/downloads/gcc/utils/binutils`

**glibc-2.16+** solves this problem but I'm restricted by the kernel version. To fix this problem I made changes to `glibc-2.15/(config*in|Makeconfig)` as mentioned in http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2012-06/msg00632.html but this results in configure error(caught signal 2).

Any pointers to help resolve the issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Glibc *should* work with older kernels, shouldn't it? It just disables the optional features. Of course, that probably only goes so far ....

Anyway, the magic build option will be something like this:

```
/path/to/source/configure --enable-kernel=2.6.18 ...blah..
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion by explicitly mentioning the kernel to be 2.6.18 but configure fails. 
`configure: error: GNU libc requires kernel header files from
Linux 2.6.19 or later to be installed before configuring.
The kernel header files are found usually in /usr/include/asm and
/usr/include/linux; make sure these directories use files from
Linux 2.6.19 or later.`